# Get form data in conditional json format

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a html form like:

```
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="1"/>
  <input type="text" name="custom" value="a"/>
  <input type="text" name="custom" value="b"/>
  <input type="text" name="custom" value="c">
</form>
```

When i get form data in json format, it shows like:

```
{id: 1, custom: c}  //get the last value only
```

I need this data such a way that:

- if `name="custom"` exist only one time in my form, json will be

  ```
  {id: 1, custom: c} // it is working now
  ```
- if `name="custom"` exist multiple times in my form, json will be

  ```
  {
  id: 1,
  multiple:[
     {custom: a},
     {custom: b},
     ...
    ]
  }
  ```

  OR

  ```
  {id: 1, custom:[a, b, c]}
  ```

my method to get json data is:

```
function getFormData($form){ 
  var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
  var indexed_array = {};
  $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
    indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value']; 
  });
  return indexed_array;
}
var $form = $("#my-form");
var data = getFormData($form);
```

How can figure out this problem?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: where is your method to convert form data to json?

Comment: My initial thought is using name="custom[]", which will then make custom an array: {id: 1, custom: ["a","b","c"]}

Comment: @gurvinder, my method is:

function getFormData($form){
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};
    
    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });

    return indexed_array;
}

var $form = $("#my-form");
var data = getFormData($form);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/ check this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some solution

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="" id="my-form">
        <input type="text" name="id" value="1"/>
        <input type="text" name="custom" value="a"/>
        <input type="text" name="custom" value="b"/>
        <input type="text" name="custom" value="c">
    </form>

    <script>
        var objData = {};
        var tmpArray = [];
        var allInputs = document.getElementById("my-form").elements;
        for (var i = 0, len = allInputs.length; i < len; i++) {
            var existInArray = false;
            for (var j = 0, lenArr = tmpArray.length; j < lenArr; j++) {
                if (tmpArray[j] == allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')) {
                    existInArray = true;
                }
            }
            if (!existInArray) {
                tmpArray.push(allInputs[i].getAttribute('name'));
                objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')] = allInputs[i].getAttribute('value');
            } else {
                if (Object.prototype.toString.call(objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')]) === '[object Array]') {
                    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')].push(allInputs[i].getAttribute('value'));
                } else {
                    var tmpValue = objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')];
                    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')] = [];
                    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')].push(tmpValue);
                    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')].push(allInputs[i].getAttribute('value'))
                }
            }
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(objData));

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

also in Plkr  https://plnkr.co/edit/zEid9XRXQYfxNHrXTsxu?p=preview

AND if you want insert key multiple use this after last else

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')] ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')].multiple.push(allInputs[i].getAttribute('value'));
} else {
    var tmpValue = objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')];
    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')] = { 'multiple' : []};
    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')].multiple.push(tmpValue);
    objData[allInputs[i].getAttribute('name')].multiple.push(allInputs[i].getAttribute('value'))
}
```